# JButton only appears on mouse over

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton

I have the problem that my JButton only appears if I move the mouse over the position where the button should be. I tried a lot of sollutions like use paintComponents() instead of paint(), use repaint(), setVisible() and so on but nothing helped me. I'm sure that the problem is the TextArea, if I comment this out: `pnlBackground.add(txt);`, the Button pops up when the program starts, but the TextArea dont shows up. Any ideas?

```
public class MediGraph extends JFrame {

private JPanel pnlBackground;
private JPanel pnlGraph;
private JTextArea txt;
private JButton btnFileChooser;
private JFileChooser fcFiler;
public static String fileName = "Langzeitblutdruck_PID34567.txt";

public MediGraph(){
    //JFrame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(900,420));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("MediGraph");
    //pnlBackground
    pnlBackground = new JPanel();
    pnlBackground.setLayout(null);
    pnlBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 420);
    //pnlGraph
    pnlGraph = new JPanel();
    pnlGraph.setLayout(null);
    pnlGraph.setBounds(0, 0, 650, 370);
    pnlBackground.add(pnlGraph);
    //JTextArea
    txt = new JTextArea();
    txt.setBounds(620, 5, 270, 305);
    //fcFiler
    fcFiler = new JFileChooser();
    //btnFileChooser
    btnFileChooser = new JButton("Datei einlesen");
    btnFileChooser.setBounds(250, 335, 135, 30);
    btnFileChooser.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fcFiler.showOpenDialog(btnFileChooser);
            if(fcFiler.getSelectedFile() != null){
                fileName = fcFiler.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(fileName);
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    pnlBackground.add(txt);
    pnlBackground.add(btnFileChooser);  
    add(pnlBackground);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    g = this.pnlGraph.getGraphics();
    Color HeretsuEnt = new Color (204, 0, 0); //Farben für Achsen, Firmenlogo und Systole
    Color Greeen = new Color (0, 195, 0);
    Color Indigo = new Color (128,0,128);
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 700);
    //x und y Achse
    g.setColor (Indigo);
    g.drawLine (27, 15, 27, 300);
    g.drawLine (27, 300, 600, 300);
    // Linien der Achsenabschnitte
    for (int i = 27; i < 600; i += 20) {
      g.drawLine (i, 298, i, 302);
      if(i < 300)
      g.drawLine (24, i, 30, i);
    }
    //Beschriftung Abschnitte
            //y-Achse
    g.drawString("100", 5, 213);
    g.drawString("200", 5, 113);
    g.drawString("300", 5, 13);
    g.drawString("Werte",35, 23);
            //x-Achse
    g.drawString("5",  125, 314);
    g.drawString("10", 225, 314);
    g.drawString("15", 325, 314);
    g.drawString("20", 425, 314);
    g.drawString("25", 525, 314);
    g.drawString("in Stunden",548, 319);

    // Linen für die Pfeilspitzen 
    g.drawLine (605, 300, 595, 295);
    g.drawLine (605, 300, 595, 305);
    g.drawLine (27, 14, 22, 22);
    g.drawLine (27, 14, 32, 22);

    //Firmenlogo :)
    g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 20));
    g.setColor(HeretsuEnt);
    g.drawString ("Heretsu Enterprises",400, 355);

    //Legende
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 15));
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(100, 320, 120, 320);
    g.drawString("Puls", 30, 325);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine(100, 340, 120, 340);
    g.drawString("Diastole", 30, 345);

    g.setColor(Greeen);
    g.drawLine(100, 360, 120, 360);
    g.drawString("Systole", 30, 365);

    //Graphen
    Untersuchung untersuchung = new Untersuchung();
    Auslesen.lesen(fileName);
    ArrayList messwerte = untersuchung.getMesswerte();
    g.setColor(HeretsuEnt);
    g.drawString(fileName,200, 15);

    String ausgabe =  "  Datum   "+"      Uhrzeit   "+"    Systole   "+"Diastole   "+"Puls   "+"\n ";
    for(int i = 0;i < messwerte.size();i++){
      ausgabe += "" +""+((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getDatum() + "    " + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getUhrzeit()
              + "         " + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getSystole() + "          " + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getDiastole() + "          " + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(i)).getPuls() +"\n ";

    }   
    txt.setText(ausgabe);
    for (int j = 4; j < messwerte.size() - 1; j++) {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawLine((j*27/4),(-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j)).getPuls())/-1,(j+1)*27/4, (-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j+1)).getPuls())/-1);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.drawLine((j*27/4),(-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j)).getDiastole())/-1,(j+1)*27/4,(-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j+1)).getDiastole())/-1); 
      g.setColor(Greeen);
      g.drawLine((j*27/4),(-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j)).getSystole())/-1,(j+1)*27/4,(-300 + ((Messwert)messwerte.get(j+1)).getSystole())/-1); 
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MediGraph();

}}
```

Comment: You have multiple problems in your code, enough to convince me that you are missing significant elements of how Java Swing works. You should try creating some smaller examples or following some tutorials to improve your skills

Comment: Don't use null layouts; don't override paint and the not call super.paint; don't use getGraphics, especially when your painting one component and try to use the graphics from another component; don't modify the state of any component directly or indirectly from within any paint method

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems...

Let's start with `setLayout(null);`

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

While it might "seem" like a good idea, it really isn't and you will end up no end of little niggly issues which appear, almost randomly, on different computers.  The layout management API has been designed to overcome these issues and make your life easier.

Next, painting...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g = this.pnlGraph.getGraphics();
```

You override `paint` of `JFrame`, which in of itself is not recommended, but that then you fail to call `super.paint`, which is preventing the frame from not only painting itself, but also any child components.

Now, if that wasn't bad enough, you then grab a reference to another component's `Graphics` context and paint IT from within the frame's `paint` method.  Painting should paint the CURRENT component only...

Never use `getGraphics`, seriously, this is not how painting is done in Swing.  It can return `null` and whatever you paint to will be destroyed on the next paint cycle of the component.  A component can be painted separately from it's container, so a container may not know that it's child components have been updated for some reason (for example, when a mouse enters or exits them)

And then...from within the frame's `paint` method you call `txt.setText(ausgabe);`...

You should NEVER update the state of the component or any child components directly or indirectly from within any `paint` method.  This will cause an infinite loop of repaint requests which will eventually consume your CPU cycles and make your program unusable.

I suggest you go back to basics and take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

I'd also recommend that:

- You make use of appropriate layouts
- Create a custom component for your graph, extending from `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  In there you need to perform the painting operations you need to render the graph ONLY.  Also make sure you are not breaking the paint chain and make sure you call `super.paintComponent` BEFORE you perform any custom painting
- Not override `paint` of `JFrame`